# String.Format for Integer is Incorrect in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, string-formatting

This should not happen, so I must be missing something simple.

In the below VB function, I am trying to generate a list of part numbers to display on the screen using this format statement:

```
ticket = String.Format("{0:000}-{1:00000}-{2:00}", storeNumber, order, release)
```

With that, **ticket** should have the format `xxx-yyyyy-zz` so that the ticket is human readable and the other parts of my application can parse this data.

```
Public Shared Function GetShipTickets(storeNumber As Integer, auditor As String, startDate As DateTime) As ShipTickets
    Dim list As New ShipTickets(auditor)
    list.Display = String.Format("Since {0:MMMM d}.", startDate)
    Const sqlCmd As String =
        "SELECT TICKET_STORE, TICKET_ORDER, TICKET_RELEASE " &
        "FROM TBLRELHDR " &
        "WHERE TICKET_STORE=@TICKET_STORE AND STATUS='C' AND @CREATE_DATE<=CREATE_DATE " &
        "ORDER BY TICKET_ORDER, TICKET_RELEASE, CREATE_DATE; "
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Using cmd As New DB2Command(sqlCmd, Db2CusDta)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("TICKET_STORE", DB2Type.SmallInt).Value = storeNumber
        cmd.Parameters.Add("CREATE_DATE", DB2Type.Char, 8).Value = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", startDate)
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
    End Using
    If 0 < table.Rows.Count Then
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Dim order As String = String.Format("{0}", row("TICKET_ORDER")).Trim().ToUpper()
            Dim release As String = String.Format("{0}", row("TICKET_RELEASE")).Trim().ToUpper()
            Dim ticket As String = String.Format("{0:000}-{1:00000}-{2:00}", storeNumber, order, release)
            list.Add(ticket)
        Next
    End If
    list.Sort()
    Return list
End Function
```

It is not working, though.

[image: VS_debugger_screenshot]

Also, when I view my data on the screen, it is not displaying correctly either:

[image: screen_screenshot]

### What is going on?

VB is not my strongest programming language. Either there is some nuance of VB that I am unaware of or the compiler is messing up.

Using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format "{2:00}" works on integers, not strings.  It won't automatically convert a string consisting of digits into an integer.  Manually convert the strings to integers:

```
Dim ticket As String = String.Format("{0:000}-{1:00000}-{2:00}", 
                                     CInt(storeNumber), 
                                     CInt(order), 
                                     CInt(release))
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you Darryl! I couldn't figure out what was causing that.